What do to when I get Error when library and lockfile are out of sync?
I am trying to deploy my golem shiny app on shiny io.
I am getting the following errors when I am attempting to publish the app:
ℹ Capturing R dependencies from renv.lock
Error in `parseRenvDependencies()`:
! Library and lockfile are out of sync
ℹ Use renv::restore() or renv::snapshot() to synchronise
ℹ Or ignore the lockfile by adding to your .rscignore
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─rsconnect::deployApp(...)
 2.   └─rsconnect:::bundleApp(...)
 3.     └─rsconnect:::createAppManifest(...)
 4.       └─rsconnect:::bundlePackages(...)
 5.         └─rsconnect:::computePackageDependencies(...)
 6.           └─rsconnect:::parseRenvDependencies(bundleDir)
 7.             └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 8.               └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted

I have tried to restore but it seems it doesn't download the DBI package:
# Installing packages --------------------------------------------------------
- Installing DBI ...                            FAILED
Error in if (cond) return(expr) : the condition has length > 1
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(R(), args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/bin/R' CMD config CC 2>&1' had status 1

Do not know where is the issue? How to solve it?

I'm assuming you've already made sure your renv.lock file is updated by running renv::snapshot() in the console before publishing?

I have actually succeeded with your suggestion. Thank you. The only difference was - to choose step 2 from the automated alternative renv::snapshot() : What do you want to do?
1: Snapshot, just using the currently installed packages.
2: Install the packages, then snapshot.
3: Cancel, and resolve the situation on your own.

Great! The solution was in the debug statement all along ;) Thanks for sharing the details of what you did as well for future users. Make sure to mark the question as closed.

how to mark it as closed?

Only way is to provide an answer and accept it.

I received this error despite renv::snapshot(). Closing the project and reopen then rsconnect::deployApp() fixed the issue and app was able to deploy successfully.
